# Filter by bound on Google Earth Engine not covering the whole of bound feature

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I tried to filter Sentinel-2 image collection by bound, then I visualized  the first in the collection after clipping to the bound feature.
The problem is that the returned images does not cover the whole bound feature, probably because the feature extends beyond one image row.

Is there a way to fix this? maybe with composites?

This is the code I used:

```
var start = ee.Date('2020-7-5');
var end = start.advance(1,'month')
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start,end)
    
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                          .filterBounds(table)
                          .filterDate(dateRange)
                          .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE');
var img = s2.first() ; 
print(img);
var param = {'bands':['B4', 'B3','B2'], 'min':400 , 'max':3500 }
Map.centerObject(table,12);
Map.addLayer(img.clip(table), param, 'se img');
Map.addLayer(table,{},'table')
```

The map window[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because when doing

```
var img = s2.first();
```

you're only getting the first image of the imageCollection. What you need to do is calculate a median or a mosaic over the entire collection which will then cover your entire area, something like this:

```
var img = s2.median();
```

Comment: Please can you show me how to create a mosaic over the collection?

Comment: Sorry this is a Q&A forum not a tutorial section but these two links are a very good start https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic and https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless

Comment: Thank you for the links.